# How Flutter pops up a notification type page

Tags: dart, flutter

I am working on a flutter version of the chat app. I think when I am using this app, someone sends me a video chat request. My app should pop up an answering page and display it at the top. How to pop up this page? The person who initiates the chat request can pop up using
 `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => NewPage()));`
but the answer page of another person should be passively popped up.How to achieve it?

Comment: how to achieve what? how to pop a top `Route`?

Comment: I think I made a mistake, it should be pushing a top route (Chinese pops up and shows a similar meaning), that is, no matter which page of the APP I currently have, as long as there is a notification message (that is, video call), in the APP A page will be pushed.